# How to write formatted text to a file in PHP

Tags: php

What im trying to do is to merge the filename and contents of 25 text files respectively to a seperate word file, which i have achieved But the Condition is that the filename should be the heading(in h1 tag) and the content of each file should be on next line.How to achieve this?

```
<?php
    for($i = 1; $i <= 25; $i++) {
        $myfile = fopen('text/text_file'.$i.'.txt', 'w+')  or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = "This is the content of ".$i." file";    
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fclose($myfile);
    }
    $target = "text/";
    $merged_file = 'text/merged.doc';
    $files = scandir($target);
    $myfile = fopen($merged_file, 'w+');
    print_r($files);
    foreach($files as $index => $value) {
        if($value !== "." && $value !== ".." && substr($value, -3, 3) == "txt") {
            $Data = substr($value, 0, -4)."\n".file_get_contents($target.$value); 
            $da= "<h2>".$Data."</h2>";
            fwrite($myfile, $da."\n");
        }
    }
    fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: We need the relevant input, the current output and the expected output to be able to help. Your code is too specific that we, without knowledge, can help you very much.

Comment: What is failing? What is your problem/question?

Comment: `doc` is a binary document format, you can't read the text from it or write text to it without relevant software libraries. It's also a closed proprietary format owned by Microsoft so libraries for PHP (or in general) are not that good with dealing with it.